# What is "The sum of true positives and false positives are equal to zero for some labels." mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit learn to perform cross validation using `StratifiedKFold` to compute the `f1 score`, but it says that some of my labels have the sum of true positives and false positives are equal to zero for some labels. I thought using `StratifiedKFold` should prevent this? Why am I getting this problem?

Also, is there a way to get the confusion matrix from the `cross_val_score` function?

Answer (score 0):

Your classifier is probably classifying all data points as negative, so there are no positives. You can check that is the case by looking at the confusion matrix ([docs and example here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix)). It's hard to tell what is happening without information about your data and choice of classifier, but common causes include:

- bug in your code. Check your training data contains negative data points, and that these data points contain non-zero features.
- inappropriate classifier parameters. If using Naive Bayes, check your class biases. If using SVM, try using grid search over parameter values.

The sklearn `classification_report` function may come in handy ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)).

Re your second question: stratification ensures that each fold contains [roughly the same proportion of data points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) from all classes. This does not mean your classifier will perform sensibly.

---

Update:

In a classification task (and especially when class imbalance is present) you are trading off precision for recall. Depending on your application, you can set your classifier so it does well most of the time (i.e. high accuracy) or so that it can detect the few points that you care about (i.e. high recall of the smaller classes). For example, if the task is to forward support emails to the right department, you want high accuracy. It is somewhat acceptable to misclassify the kind of email you get once a year, because you only upset one person. If your task is to detect posts by sexual predators on a children's forum, you definitely do not want to miss any of them, even if the price is that a few posts will get incorrectly flagged. Bottom line: you should optimise for your application.

Are you micro or macro averaging recall? In the former case, more weight will be given to the frequent classes (which is similar to optimising for accuracy), and in the latter all classes will have the same weight.

Comment: When I try to do a grid search on SVM with accuracy, it gives me parameter values which make the classifier give a lot of preference to 3 of my classes that are highly represented in my dataset. When I try to score the grid search on something like recall, the accuracy suffers. Anyway I can improve my accuracy without making the classifier too biased?